# Check for 12V with Arduino (Two resistors and a diode)

Tags: arduino, voltage, resistors, diodes, 12v

I need to read the presence of 12V on one of the lines of the board. I want to read using Arduino UNO.

I found the following scheme:
[image]

Is this scheme correct?

Comment: Ooopps. UPD. [IMG](http://joxi.ru/zANDJ7dhvl1Vom.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

No the schematic is incorrect, there will be a constant 5 V on ARDUINO_PIN because you've connected it straight to +5V.

Also, general convention for drawing schematics is to have the input on the left and output on the right.

The diodes are not doing anything either.

If the Arduino board is working on that +5V supply then all you need is a resistor divider that makes about 5 V from the 12 V, like so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPWmNb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is no need for additional diodes.
When an Arduino is operating on 5 V then an input voltage above about 5V/2 = 2.5 V is considered a "1" so 4.8 V is more than enough.

Comment: I thought that this diode could save the pin, if suddenly, instead of 12V, more voltage would come.

Comment: For that the diodes would have to be in forward mode then a negative voltage would be needed on the 12 V line. But don't worry about this. It is better to handle too high voltages by **limiting the current** and that is done here by the 15 kohm resistor. If the 12 V would become 24 V for example, your Arduino would still be OK. R2 would limit the current and also, there are protection diodes inside the Arduino chip. They prevent ARDUINO_PIN from becoming more than about 6 V. But that **only** works if the current is limited, which is what R2 does.